# Optimize ngFor in Ionic when page is loading too many data

Tags: api, ionic-framework, ngfor, javascript-databinding

currently I'm working on an Ionic page which get data from an API, roughly 50,000 items and save them in `selectedItem` (array). I have to list them all like this:

```
<ion-list class="main-item-container">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of selectedItem; trackBy: trackSelectedItem">             
       // Stuff here (item's thumbnail, title ...    
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I have applied the `<ion-infinite-scroll>` at the end of the list, used the trackBy function as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324460/how-to-improve-performance-of-ngfor-loop)

But the problem is just slightly solved. The page is still suffered from lags and delays for about 1sec on computer and 2sec on tablet devices, even happends when I toggle the Menuside.

Question is: Is there any other way to improve this situation? I can think of one way data-binding items to those list, so perhaps the page will ignore the list once data is binded.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Infinite scroll or virtual scroll

Here are the links:

[Infinite scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/)

[Virtual Scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/)

confused between which one to choose? here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733750/what-are-differences-and-use-cases-for-virtual-vs-infinite-scroll-in-ionic-3)